# Problems with importing events from Facebook

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am to import information about events from Facebook.
I've generated the token, downloaded all the needed libraries.
Here is my code (for example I wanted to download events linked to "Poetry"):

```
import urllib3
import facebook
import requests
token = 'xyz'
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = token, version = 2.7)
events = graph.request(‘/search?q=Poetry&type=event&limit=10000’)
```

Unfortunately an error occurs
[image]

How can it be fixed?
I have one more question - how is it possible to download information over some events in a particular location?
I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use apostrophes to enclose a string:

```
graph.request('/search?q=Poetry&type=event&limit=10000')
```